# How can I set a breakpoint to a function in Xcode4?

Tags: debugging, xcode4, breakpoints

How can I set a breakpoint to a function such as `CGErrorBreakpoint` in Xcode4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a symbolic break point for it.  To do that, switch to the Breakpoint Navigator (2nd one from the right in the navigator tabbar).  Then press the + button at the bottom of the window.  It'll allow you to add the symbolic breakpoint.